# Samples from a black box

Tags: sample

Say I have a black-box that contains a lot of numbers (integer numbers). The quantity is very very large and the range of the numbers is finite but unknown (the numbers can be repetitive). I want to know what would be the minimum amount of samples I can randomly pick up from the box so that the values are representative from the black box. For that I do the following: I pick up an initial set of 10 numbers, then I determine the minimum, maximum, median, and average (statistical parameters). Next I pick up a new set of 20 numbers (whole new set), and again determine the statistical parameters. I do this procedure with 30, 40, ....., 1000 samples. In each step I pick up a whole new set (having returned the previous set to the box and "mix it"). Then, I would say that the minimum amount of samples is when I see that the statistical parameters “does not change much” with the increase of the number of samples.

Now my question is, what if I modify the previous procedure in this way: I pick up an initial set of 10 numbers, then I determine the minimum, maximum, median, and average. **Next I pick up an additional set of 10 numbers, so that with the previous set I can have a set of 20 numbers**, and again determine the statistical parameters. Next, pick up an **additional 10 numbers** so that with the previous set I can have a set of 30 numbers, and again determine the statistical parameters. I do this procedure with 30, 40, ....., 1000 samples. In this case in each step I am just pick up 10 additional numbers, instead of picking up the whole set. Again here, the minimum amount of samples is when I see that the statistical parameters “does not change much” with the increase of the samples.

I have seen that doing the first and second procedure, I get different minimal amount of samples, so which procedure would be the right one for my purpose, the first or the second?

Any reference that can help me to understand better it would be appreciated.

Comment: Google "group sequential sampling design".  Instead of guessing what might work, your time would be better spent researching what does work and why.

Comment: @whuber hi, could you please recommend me a lecture? I dont find something that I can relate to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either set of 1000 samples is equally representative of the underlying population. It doesn't matter whether you pick them 10 at a time or all at once. In the sequential sampling, all you're seeing is that when you add 10 samples to a sample of 990, you'll wind up with something that looks *very much* like the 990 samples you already had, and that if you had selected 1000 entirely new samples, you wouldn't get something that looked as much alike (simply because you're not keeping 99% of the data the same). But that doesn't mean that your 1000 samples selected 10 at a time is any more representative than 1000 samples selected all at once. Either way, all you have at the end is a list of 1000 random samples - those samples cannot be distinguished in any way (from the list of samples, one cannot distinguish how they were picked), so they're indistinguishable in terms of their representativeness as well.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with what you wrote. My intention is to determine the minimal amount of samples by looking at the convergence of the statistical parameters vs the numbers of samples. So if I dont  see convergence with 1000 samples, then I would extent the evaluations until 10 000, or more if necessary. But I see that using the second procedure (adding additional 10 samples), the convergence is "easier" than using the first procedure (a new set of samples). So I dont know which one should I use.

Comment: @BurNor Right, my point is that convergence of the sequential sampling says more about the size of the added samples than convergence. Adding 10 samples at a time will yield "convergence" because you're changing the sample by a progressively smaller fraction each time. You could add samples 5 at a time or even 1 at a time and get "convergence" even faster simply because you're changing the sample by even less. None of that indicates that you've sampled the population sufficiently to estimate some parameter like the mean within some bounds, though.

Comment: @BurNor Basically, seeing that 1000 samples is virtually identical to the same 1000 samples plus one more is wholly unsurprising - adding one sample simply can't move the summary statistics by very much. The better measure of variability is to look at two independent samples of 1000, and see how much those differ. Simply adding samples to an existing cohort will always yield lower variability, since you're comparing two samples that are *not independent* of one another.

Comment: " The better measure of variability is to look at two independent samples of 1000" so the first procedure (as explained in my post) would be the right one, right? because there each 10, 20, ...990, 1000 samples are independent from the previous ones. Do  you have a reference that you can recommend related to that topic? Thannks again.

Comment: @BurNor Correct, the first option is better. You can read up on the concept of standard error, which essentially describes the standard deviation *of a parameter estimate* rather than the population. The standard error of the mean will tell you how much variability you'd expect to see in an estimate of the mean. Empirically, you can sample the mean independently many times (draw many independent samples of N=1000 and calculate the mean for each), and see how wide the distribution over means is.

Comment: I was advised by a supervisor and other colleague that the second option is the normal procedure. By now I have not found a reason why the first or second option is better or worse.

Comment: @BurNor You can still do something useful with the second approach, but the cutoff for what you consider a "small enough change in parameters" must be *specifically tailored* to your sampling approach and cannot be generalized. Adding 100 new samples at a time will always result in bigger changes than adding 1 new sample at a time, so you couldn't use some fixed numerical cutoff to decide when N is large enough. Conversely, with repeated resampling of the full dataset, you only need to worry about the standard error and have no effect whatsoever from the sampling methodology.